# How can I automate a function's return value that is not string?

Tags: python, string, function

I want to use the return value with classes but I don't know how to make it automatic.    Let's say I give enemy("e21") and it returns e21

I've tried replacing the return value with string but It didn't work with my class

```
# <-- means separate file (and they are imported)
def e_info(input1, monster):
    if input1 == "name":
        return monster.name
#
def enemy(input2):
    if input2 == "e1":
        return e1
    if input2 == "e2":
        return e2
#
print(2 * "\n" + e_info("name", m.enemy(enemy_info)))
#
class Enemy:

    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

e1 = Enemy("Test1")
```

Comment: your question cannot be understood, what class? what are `e1` and `e2`? show small examples of their definition and of `input2`

Answer (score 1):

The usual way to do this is to make a dictionary that maps the strings to the values:

```
def func(input2):
    mapping = {
        "e1": e1,
        "e2": e2,
    }
    return mapping[input2]
```

But this assumes that all possible values of `input2` are known in advance.  If this isn't the case, and `input2` can be any arbitrary value, then you'll have to use something like `exec()` as in @Victor's answer.

Comment: There existing code "doesn't work", so this will also not work- the logic is the same